# Proof verification regarding asymptotics

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

> Prove $f(z)=o(\phi (z))$ implies $f(z)=O(\phi (z))$ as $ z \to 0$.

My proof is:

The assumed statement is $$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{ f(z)}{\phi (z)}=0$$

That statement implies the function $\frac{ f(z)}{\phi (z)}$ is bounded by a  constant $K>0$. Therefore, $\left|\frac{ f(z)}{\phi (z)}\right| \leq K$ which implies $|f(z)|<K|\phi (z)|$.

Is this true correct?

Comment: It would be good if you could flesh out the claim "That statement implies...," but that is the correct argument.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok thanks, what would be a better thing to use because I tend to use the word imply inappropriately.

Comment: Actually, technically, that step isn't valid. If $\phi(z)=z$ and $f(z)=z^2$ then it is true that $f(z)=o(\phi(z))$ as $z\to 0$, but it is not true that $f(z)/\phi(z)$ is bounded. You have to be more precise.

Comment: We cannot claim that the ratio is bounded, but we can certainly say that there is a $K\gt 0$ such that $|f(z)|\le K|\phi(z)|$ for $z$ close enough to $0$.